# libexpect5.45.so: cannot open shared object file: Error 40

Tags: ubuntu, expect

Делал так: http://sitefresh.net/articles/49-expect-ustanovka-v-ubuntu-16-04.html
однако при попытке выполнить сценарий на ubuntu 16.04_x64 выдаёт ошибку:

```
expect expect.sh
expect: error while loading shared libraries: libexpect5.45.so: cannot open shared object file: Error 40
```

Помогите побороть.

Comment: sudo apt-get install expect - лечит, но хотелось бы понять причину, дабы работать с исходниками, теперь видимо не скоро буду этот вопрос разбирать.